# All combinations of a list where each element can have few values

Tags: c#, list, recursion

Well problem i need help with is simple:
You have list of length x.
Then you have array of numbers of length y.
I need to generate all possible lists of length x, that elements are from array.

I think recursion is solution but don't know how to create it...

For example:

List has length 5.

Arrays has length 3 -> [0, 1, 2]

So generated lists should be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
.
.
.
[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Array will always have less or equal number of elements in it than there is elements in list. So its always y<=x

Comment: What have you coded so far ?

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question.

Comment: Please prepare some code with these arrays, we will help to improve it. With no code at all nobody will help here.

Comment: Hint: this is the *n-ary Cartesian product* of the array with itself. If you can solve the more general problem of making the n-ary Cartesian product of n arrays then this problem is a special case.

Comment: Not homework, its just something i need for further progress on project i'm doing... No code so far, since i dont know how to begin with that.

Comment: @EricLippert - I like how googling the italics in your question followed by c# returns a link to your own blog post (Link 4)

Comment: @Sayse That's not a coincidence.

Comment: @user2414828: The problem here then is **I don't know how to begin to solve a problem**. What you need help with here is your problem solving skills. A good book to read is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It -- notice that my suggestion to you was the "Generalization heuristic".

Comment: I like how even the comments of Eric Lippert require studying on my part, seriously, I feel so stupid. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion, as you proposed:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetLists<T>(T[] elements, int length)
{
    if(length == 1) foreach(var t in elements)
        yield return new[] { t };
    else foreach(var t in elements) foreach(var list in GetLists(elements, length - 1))
        yield return new[] { t }.Concat(list).ToArray();
}
```

This does not only work for numbers, but is generic, so you can use any type.

Comment: The OP is looking for combinations with repetition, which is different than what you have here.